# what is the name of this cactus/succulent?

Tags: identification, cactus

[image: identify this]

Hi everyone, can anyone identify this cactus/succulent? Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like an Epiphyllum (or Orchid Cactus):

https://adamsjunglecacti.com.au/products/epi-hybrid-kiwi-honey-dew-515
It is a popular houseplant and is very hardy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is *Pfeiffera monacantha*, it is an epiphytic cactus which means it doesn't grow in soil but on trees.

See [here](https://worldofsucculents.com/pfeiffera-monacantha/) for more information about how to grow and take care of this plant.

Comment: Thanks a million  Ben and TimNevins!  Great stuff

Answer (score 0):

Pfieffera is the old species name, the currently accepted name is Lepisium monacantha. Feel free to use whatever name suits you, though.